# Rails route to get a resource using query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

I would like to have a custom route querystring based, to access a specified resource. For example:

*/opportunities/rent/san-miguel-de-tucuman?id=45045*

That route should map to the action OpportunitiesController#show, with the resource id 45045.

Thanks in advance!!!

**Updated**

This are my current routes:

- get 'oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman/:id', to: "opportunities#show"
- get 'oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman', to: "opportunities#index"

**So, if I navigate to the /oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman?id=123456 route, it go to the Opportunities#index action.**

P/S: sorry, I forget to mention that I have a similar route for the index action.

Comment: Can we see the output of `rake routes` ? Also, how does your routes.rb file look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your custom  routes as:

```
resources: opportunities, except: :show

get '/opportunities/rent/san-miguel-de-tucuman/:id' => 'opportunities#show', :as => 'opportunities_show'
```

and pass your 'id' as opportunities_show_path(**id**)

**EDIT**

Change your routes as:

```
get 'oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman/:id' => "opportunities#show", :as => 'opportunities_show'

get 'oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman' => "opportunities#index", :as => "opportunities_index"
```

Now when you want to access your show page just use **opportunities_show_path(:id =>123456 )**

And for index page use **opportunities_index_path**

Comment: This are my current routes:

get 'oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman/:id', to: "opportunities#show"
get 'oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman', to: "opportunities#index"
So, if I navigate to the /oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman?id=123456 route, it go to the Opportunities#index action.

P/S: sorry, I forget to mention that I have a similar route for the index action.

Comment: if want to access index action then your path must be like /oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman and if you want to access show action then path must be  /oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman/123456

Comment: that didn't work, because if I use the url /oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman?id=123456 that routes to the collection action => Opportunities#index

That should route to the action Opportunities#show action.

Comment: but why are you passing id like query string (?id=1234567) for show action, just use it as  /oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman/123456

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
match '/opportunities/rent/san-miguel-de-tucuman/:id', :to => 'opportunities#show', :via => :get
```

and pass a object to the path so created. Eg:-

**something_path(@object)**, here @object is object that with **id** which will be passed in routes

Comment: This are my current routes:

get 'oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman/:id', to: "opportunities#show"
get 'oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman', to: "opportunities#index"
So, if I navigate to the /oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman?id=123456 route, it go to the Opportunities#index action.

P/S: sorry, I forget to mention that I have a similar route for the index action.

Comment: @AugustoPedraza An **ID** should only be passed to **show, edit and destroy** methods as a best routing practice

Comment: you are right.
However, on RESTfull, when you use querystring into a collection route, you are filter that collection.
But, considering that it is blurred for Rails, I will follow the standard rails routes conventions. IMHO

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Query string parameter

```
// /opportunities/rent/san-miguel-de-tucuman?id=45045
match '/opportunities/rent/san-miguel-de-tucuman', :to => 'opportunities#show', :as => "show_opportunity", :via => :get
```

**Option 2**

Add id like new parameter. More friendly.

```
// /opportunities/rent/san-miguel-de-tucuman/45045
match '/opportunities/rent/san-miguel-de-tucuman/:id', :to => 'opportunities#show', :as => "show_opportunity", :via => :get
```

In both cases, you need to call the route like this:

```
show_opportunity_url(:id => 45045)
```

In your controller you will get the id in `params[:id]`

Comment: This are my current routes:

get 'oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman/:id', to: "opportunities#show"
get 'oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman', to: "opportunities#index"
So, if I navigate to the /oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman?id=123456 route, it go to the Opportunities#index action.

P/S: sorry, I forget to mention that I have a similar route for the index action.

Comment: If your Opportunities#index route is this `/oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman`, /oportunidades/alquiler/san-miguel-de-tucuman?id=123456 will always fire index method because ?id=123456 is a query string parameter, not a rails route parameter. Add your index route to know exactly what rails will do for each case.